# Fluent NHibernate and MySQL cast syntax?

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table in MySQL which has a string column 'Id' of the form "Xnnnn" where nnnn is a number.

I want to find the largest nnnn defined.  So I have:

```
var c = s.CreateCriteria(typeof(Item))
  .AddOrder(Order.Desc(
    Projections.Cast(
       NHibernateUtil.Int32,
       Projections.SqlFunction("substring", NHibernateUtil.String, 
                               Projections.Property("Id"), 
                               Projections.Constant(2), Projections.Constant(10)))
       ))
       .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id"))
       .SetMaxResults(1)
       .List<string>();
```

But NHibernate generates the SQL:

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_ FROM `Item` this_ 
  ORDER BY cast(substring(this_.Id, ?p0, ?p1) as INTEGER) desc limit ?p2
```

Which MySQL doesn't like ... it insists on:

```
cast(substring(this_.Id, ?p0, ?p1) as SIGNED INTEGER)
```

I've tried various types in the cast and none of them produce the right output.  Everything else I need to do with the mapping works just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not configuring a dialect explicitly, I am using Fluent NHibernate, and I assume it is handled there.  When I tried setting it in the configuration there was an exception to the effect that the property was already set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in NH. It's fixed in the 3.0 Alpha2 version. 
See [NH-2261](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2261) and [NH-2149](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2149) for reference.

I see 2 options here:

1. Native SQL Query (session.CreateSQLQuery())
2. Upgrade to NH 3.0 (remember that it's still an Alpha, quite stable though)

Comment: 3) backport. When I reported a bug in a dialect (fixed in 3.0), fabio recommended just dropping the 3.0 provider into a custom 2.x build. That may work as well.

Comment: @Gabe Moothart: Yes, but having used that solution in the past I avoid it whenever possible. It just adds another thing to remember: "we're on the custom NH build". It is however a good option if you're applying *exactly* the same changes as already implemented in 3.0